# An interesting way to create new instance in Java

Tags: java, constructor

```
class MyClass {

}

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass g = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(g.getClass()); //print MyClass

        MyClass g2 = new MyClass(){};
        System.out.println(g2.getClass()); //print Test$1
    }       
}
```

Can someone please explain to me:

1. What does new MyClass(){} actually mean?
2. Why the different outputs?

Comment: That's an anonymous class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you place braces after a `new MyClass()` call, that is the syntax for an anonymous class that subclasses the explicit class.  The `{}` are an empty class body, so nothing is overridden, and no constructors are declared.

The output `Test$1` is different because the anonymous subclass does have an implicit name, which is the enclosing class (`Test`), then a dollar sign `$`, then a sequence number (`1`).  When compiling `Test.java`, you may notice that besides `Test.class` and `MyClass.class`, `Test1.class` also exists -- the class file for the anonymous class.  If you were to declare another anonymous subclass in the `Test` class, after your first anonymous subclass, then it would be named `Test$2`, no matter what class it actually subclasses.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. If g is a subclass of MyClass (and that is why it is able to override any method in MyClass), why does g.getClass.getName() not returned MyClass?

Comment: The variable `g` refers to an instance of the anonymous class, which is the runtime type of the object.  (The second `g`; you re-declared `g`.)  The `getClass` method returns the `Class` object corresponding to the runtime type of the object on which it's called.

Answer (score 2):

`MyClass g = new MyClass();`, this creates object of `Myclass`.

while ,   `MyClass g = new MyClass(){};` is extending `Myclass` using anonymous class.

give this a read : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

**What does new MyClass(){} actually mean ?**

It mean you have created one new Sub-class of MyClass which does not have any name. that's why it's called anonymous class.

And that Anonymous class refer by Parent class's reference variable. here, g .

For example,

Class A{
}

```
//somewhere i wrote like,
Class A = new A(){...};
Means new A(){...} is subclass of A.
for example, Class B extends A{...}, in this case Class B is sub class of A.
```

> So ultimately the class which is subclass of A which does not have any
>   name, it's called anonymous class.
>
> so just keep in mind that here you query is to anonymous[no name].